# Why does my washing machine trip the circuit breaker when plugged in?

Tags: washing-machine

My Maytag Washer (model LAT5000AAW) as working fine--no problem other than the timer wasn't working right. Replaced timer and now it sparks fire and kicks breaker as soon as plugged in. Have tried in several outlets. The washer is on outlet by itself. Please help.

The old one does it to but it didn't start doing it until after we had hooked up the new timer. I can't take the replacement timer back as they don't do returns. However, when changing out the timers we changed the wires one at a time. That's why I don't understand. How can we tell if a wire is hooked up wrong which I don't think would be the case since we changed them out one by one from old timer. Also, I don't see anything pinched. Frustrating. Could you give me the right wiring diagram for this washer and timer part #207379. Could something be wrong internally? Does anyone know what the inside of this timer is suppose to look like?

Comment: When something is sparking fire after you repair it, it's a pretty safe bet that it's not a problem with the outlet, and a generally bad idea to keep testing it out in new outlets. You're putting a lot of faith in a $10 circuit breaker to keep your house from burning down.

Comment: It sounds like the new timer is defective or wired improperly.  Tried taking it back out and examining it for skid marks?

Comment: The old one does it to but it didn't start doing it until after we had hooked up the new timer. I can't take the replacement timer back as they don't do returns. However, when changing out the timers we changed the wires one at a time. That's why I don't understand. How can we tell if a wire is hooked up wrong which I don't think would be the case since we changed them out one by one from old timer. Also, I don't see anything pinched. Frustrating. Could you give me the right wiring diagram for this washer and timer part #207379. Could something be wrong internally? Does anyone know what the in

Comment: Hi! You were unable to leave a comment because you have a couple of user accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have reversed a wire or the timer your replacement is bad. To check, try to put your old one back in. If you get it to work i.e. no sparks, no tripping breakers, then the replacement part is bad. If it still has the issues, then you have a wire incorrectly hooked up, pinch, or damaged, or you have a different issue all together.